# How to get all key in JSON object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"document":
  {"people":[
    {"name":["Harry Potter"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Male"]},
    {"name":["hermione granger"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Female"]},
  ]}
}
```

From this JSON example, I would like to get the keys such as `name`, `age`, `gender` for each people.

How to do this?

Comment: Your JSON structure is incorrect. Name, age, and gender should be single properties, not lists. It should be `{"name": "Harry Potter", "age":"18", "gender":"Male"}` (no square brackets).

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, which is just a text format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var input = {"document":
  {"people":[
    {"name":["Harry Potter"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Male"]},
    {"name":["hermione granger"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Female"]},
  ]}
}

var keys = [];
for(var i = 0;i<input.document.people.length;i++)
{
    Object.keys(input.document.people[i]).forEach(function(key){
        if(keys.indexOf(key) == -1)
        {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    });
}
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: `Object.keys called on non-object` can be here, if `people` is empty array

Comment: I think your first version was a best answer, need only check array isn't empty. Current version is too complicated :)

Comment: This is a good solution, and prevents the same keys from being added more than once

Comment: @vp_arth  Actually, that would work only for the first item in the array, say if the second or third object have some extra properties like "address", it would have failed.

Comment: It is other task with some other conditions, may be need to get only common fields of all entities.

Comment: Even to identify common fields we need to iterate all the objects in the array, So i thought this would be a better solution.

Answer (score 91):

I use `Object.keys` which is built into JavaScript Object, it will return an array of keys from given object [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const person = {
  name: "Jeeva",
  age: "22",
  gender: "Male"
}
console.log(Object.keys(person))
```

Comment: This isn't the correct solution to what was asked. All you did was simplify the problem and solve that, which won't be of any help

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new to answering questions. I will keep that in mind next time

Comment: FWIW: the accepted solution also doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 51):

Try this

```
var s = {name: "raul", age: "22", gender: "Male"}
   var keys = [];
   for(var k in s) keys.push(k);
```

Here keys array will return your keys  `["name", "age", "gender"]`

Comment: Can we have a generic solution. Like working for this:



`var object3 = {
    parent1: 42,
    parent2: [13, 12, { 'child1': 222 }],
    parent3: {
        child1: 44,
        child2: "ok",
        child3: [44, 45, 47, 48]
    },
    parent4: {
        child1: 444
    }
};`

Comment: how can we return all keys in nested objects and arrays?
like getting all keys from 
"data":{
         "user":{
                      "id": 1,
                      "name": "xyz"
              },
              "address":[
                       "street":"xyz",
                        "location: "xxx"]
}

Comment: @NisrineBouGhannam did you ever find a solution for this question - I am wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

ES6 of the day here;

```
const json_getAllKeys = data => (
  data.reduce((keys, obj) => (
    keys.concat(Object.keys(obj).filter(key => (
      keys.indexOf(key) === -1))
    )
  ), [])
)
```

And yes it can be written in very long one line;

```
const json_getAllKeys = data => data.reduce((keys, obj) => keys.concat(Object.keys(obj).filter(key => keys.indexOf(key) === -1)), [])
```

EDIT: Returns all first order keys if the input is of type array of objects

Answer (score 4):

This function should return an array of **ALL** the keys (i.e. the key names) in a JSON object **including nested key/value pairs**.

```js
function get_all_json_keys(json_object, ret_array = []) {
    for (json_key in json_object) {
        if (typeof(json_object[json_key]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(json_object[json_key])) {
            ret_array.push(json_key);
            get_all_json_keys(json_object[json_key], ret_array);
        } else if (Array.isArray(json_object[json_key])) {
            ret_array.push(json_key);
            first_element = json_object[json_key][0];
            if (typeof(first_element) === 'object') {
                get_all_json_keys(first_element, ret_array);
            }
        } else {
            ret_array.push(json_key);
        }
    }

    return ret_array
}
```

Using this function on the OP's original object

```
const op_object =
{
    "document":{
       "people":[
          {
             "name":[
                "Harry Potter"
             ],
             "age":[
                "18"
             ],
             "gender":[
                "Male"
             ]
          },
          {
             "name":[
                "hermione granger"
             ],
             "age":[
                "18"
             ],
             "gender":[
                "Female"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 }

var all_keys = [];

function get_all_json_keys(json_object, ret_array = []) {
    for (json_key in json_object) {
        if (typeof(json_object[json_key]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(json_object[json_key])) {
            ret_array.push(json_key);
            get_all_json_keys(json_object[json_key], ret_array);
        } else if (Array.isArray(json_object[json_key])) {
            ret_array.push(json_key);
            first_element = json_object[json_key][0];
            if (typeof(first_element) === 'object') {
                get_all_json_keys(first_element, ret_array);
            }
        } else {
            ret_array.push(json_key);
        }
    }

    return ret_array
}

get_all_json_keys(op_object, all_keys);

console.log(all_keys);
```

should yield

`[ 'document', 'people', 'name', 'age', 'gender' ]`

Note: This will return a **unique** list of all key names.

Answer (score 3):

```
var jsonData = { Name: "Ricardo Vasquez", age: "46", Email: "Rickysoft@gmail.com" };

for (x in jsonData) {   
  console.log(x +" => "+ jsonData[x]);  
  alert(x +" => "+  jsonData[x]);  
  }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

We must "parse" our jsonObject

```
 console.log('{"key0":"value0", "key1":"value1"}'); 
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse('{"key0":"value0", "key1":"value1"}')
    Object.keys(jsonObject).forEach(key => { 
        console.log(jsonObject[key]); //values 
        console.log(key); //keys 
    })
```